# May we provide a custom inputView for an UITextField within an UIAlertView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uialertview

UIAlertView now officially supports textfields. Finally!

The view hierarchy of the alertview is still private, of course, yet it provides references to the textfields it holds. This is needed for reading the content the user has typed in. It would allow however to also change the textfields behavior, like choosing another keyboard or even providing a custom inputview. Those features of an UITextField are all public, I'm still wondering whether those are allowed in the context of an alertview though.

So my question, as the title already gave away, is: May we provide a custom inputView for an UITextField within an UIAlertView?

Any insights greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see just the style constants to set the type of the text input and the method to retrieve the entered text. Following the maxim `everything is forbidden unless explicitly allowed`, you cannot set your own inputView.